# React JSX in Wordpress Plugin Development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I was able to get React working in my custom Wordpress Plugin but I forgot how I got it working. What I'm trying to do is use a react component I have in NPM and use it as a Wordpress plugin.

I used npm to install my component from NPM.

my-custom-plugin.php:

```
function wp_enqueue_react() {
   wp_enqueue_script('subreddit-posts',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/node_modules/react-subreddit-posts/build/index.js',
    ['wp-element'],
    '1.0',
    false
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
      'wp-react-subreddit-posts',
      plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/index.js',
      ['wp-element'],
    '1.0',
      true
    );


}

function subreddit_posts() {
    return '<div id="subreddit"></div>';
}

add_shortcode('subreddit_posts', 'subreddit_posts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_react' );
```

my index.js which is pulled in:

```
const { createElement, render } = wp.element;
console.log('script is running');

wp.element.render(
  wp.element.createElement(SubredditPosts, {
    subreddit: "aww",
    display: "gallery",
    placeholder: "http://www.codeisdead.com/img/profile/Kyle.jpg",
    width: "250px",
    height: "300px"
    },
    null), document.getElementById('subreddit')
  );
```

My console log shows. But I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: SubredditPosts is not defined
```

module seems to be the `react.production.min.js` file brought in by wp-element I believe.

Like I said I was able to get this working a few months ago but made some changes and broke something.

It seems logical to have the JS file with JSX to build with babel/webpack, but I don't remember having to use webpack or anything to build but I might be forgettin.

Comment: I'm guessing you've not properly [built](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/) the source: `react-subreddit-posts/build/index.js`. And you've not loaded `SubredditPosts` from `js/index.js`?

Comment: Did you run build command on npm? In the production, we don't access node_modules folder as I know so far.

Comment: Yeah, this is where I'm confused a bit. We enqueue the file so it is available but if I try to import it, it causes problems. Am I suppose to build the file as a normal react project? I've been following a few tutorials but they've all been very different. I'm really trying to use the wp-element Wordpress library which includes react.

Comment: Yes, solved it! Okay so I DO need to build the project first. This project is about taking npm hosted components and converting them into usable items in Wordpress. I believe I found a way to do it. I'll have my answer here and probably write a blog post about it. Thank you everyone! And thanks again @SallyCJ second post you've helped me on this week I believe

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/radekzz/wordpress-react-in-theme, you can just include script as Babel type, not JavaScript if you don't want to use webpack to print JSX. But in this case your code will not be compiled.